# How to convert a date stored in sqlite as MM/dd/yyyy to dd/MM/yyyy using jquery/javascript?

Tags: jquery, sqlite, datetime, converters

I have a date stored in sqlite in the following format mm/dd/yyyy.  I want to convert using jquery or javascript to format dd/MM/yyyy . (Eg.: 12/13/2013 to 13/12/2013)

I have tried using `$.format.date(vardate, "dd/MM/yyyy")` but that didn't work.

Comment: Check my post here > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date/16406643#16406643.

Comment: Can you post all your code?  What does vardate look like, etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var vardate = "MM/DD/YYYY";
aux = vardate.split('/');
vardate = [aux[1],aux[0],aux[2]].join('/');
console.log(vardate);
```